# Error: TIOCGPTPEER required but not available linux | lxc

Tags: linux, kernel, lxc

I am getting Error: TIOCGPTPEER required but not available when I execute lxc exec container bash.

I am using debian9 stretch

```
root@test-api:~# uname -a
Linux test-api 4.9.0-12-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.210-1+deb9u1 (2020-06-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
root@test-api:~# lxc exec w1 bash
Error: TIOCGPTPEER required but not available
```

Comment: Doesn't look as *programming* question, so it is **off-topic** on Stack Overflow.

Comment: According to the Linux kernel code, `TIOCGPTPEER` [appears](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.13-rc1/C/ident/TIOCGPTPEER) only in kernel 4.13. So you need to have at least that kernel version.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @NoorJafri yes it was fixed by LXC community it was a bug in lxd 4.0.5 . you can check now it will be working for or if  you still facing issue you could try snap refresh which should fix things

Comment: This new version had this problem as well. I had to revert :/